# prevent listings from breaking at % character

Tags: listings, line-breaking

The following listing of mangled method names works, but it breaks at the `%` character (for no apparent reason).

```
\begin{lstlisting}[breaklines, breakatwhitespace=false]
    @Exceptionnotificationdialog@ReportExceptionNotification$qqrx20System @UnicodeString83System@%Set$56Exceptionnotificationdialog@TExceptionNotificationOptiont1$i0$t1$i2$%r83System@%Set$56Exceptionnotificationdialog@TExceptionNotificaTY6J18n0Wfo24G1hyGAqTA
\end{lstlisting}
```

Output:

> @Exceptionnotificationdialog@ReportExceptionNotification$qqrx20System
>   @UnicodeString83System@%
>   Set$56Exceptionnotificationdialog@TExceptionNotificationOptiont1$i0$t1$i2$
>   %r83System@%
>   Set$56Exceptionnotificationdialog@TExceptionNotificaTY6J18n0Wfo24G1hyGAqTA

How do I stop `lstlisting` from breaking at the `%` character?

Answer (score 2):

You can make the % a letter. But be aware that listings than can break nowhere (with exception of the space) in your example, as it won't break "words":

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[breaklines, breakatwhitespace=false,alsoletter=\%]
    @Exceptionnotificationdialog@ReportExceptionNotification$qqrx20System @UnicodeString83System@%Set$56Exceptionnotificationdialog@TExceptionNotificationOptiont1$i0$t1$i2$%r83System@%Set$56Exceptionnotificationdialog@TExceptionNotificaTY6J18n0Wfo24G1hyGAqTA
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```